# Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have problem with my test in Protractor.

I need something like this:

'Find iframe, click on it, and then set value to the ng-model.'

So my code looks like:

```
browser.switchTo().frame(element(by.model('myModel')).getWebElement());
browser.findElement(by.className('testClass')).click();

var elm = element(by.model("myModel"));
elm.evaluate("fields.myModel = 'test';");
```

But unfortunately I have error like below:

```
Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: 
"both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  
This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because 
your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with 
Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details
```

This page is angular page and I don't know how to deal with it. 
I can't use 'browser.ignoreSynchronization=true', because then I have error, that angular is not defined. 
I can't also refresh browser because then I lose my content (it shows up afer clicking), so I don't know how can I do this.

Many thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iframes and protractor do not get along well. I use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled();`, then do the checks, and then switch back.
Example:

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
browser.switchTo().frame(iFrame)
//Do stuff inside iframe here. You should be treating this as a non angular page
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

Comment: don't you mean true on the last line?

Comment: @JeremyKahan I did mean true, I have edited answer. Thanks